# 'str' object has no attribute 'all',

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I want to get last data choiced by the user of a field1(a foreignkey type) from a form1(model1) already submitted and display it on a another field2(Exist on form2(model2)),

Here is my **models.py**:
**Model1:**

```
field1 = models.ForeignKey(ProfileSize, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Model2:**

```
field2 = models.ForeignKey(ProfileSize,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**ProfileSize Model:**

```
class ProfileSize(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sizes')
```

The story that I have declared a field2 as a foreignkey in model2 and I have did ModelChoiceField in forms.py To display to me just the last data entered by the user in the field1(exist in the form1) ,

Here is my **forms.py**:

```
class Form2(forms.ModelForm):
    field2 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Model1.objects.none(),)
```

I have did it with this queryset in **views.py**

```
def view2(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = Form2(request.GET, )
        form.fields['field2'].queryset = Model1.objects.filter(user=request.user).last().field1.name
```

> > > > it shows me error

```
'str' object has no attribute 'all',
```

My Question how i can filter correctly the foreignkey  to get data from another form using the queryset,

Comment: show your `ProfileSize` model please

Comment: @
SLDem , I have Edited my post Question (Under Model1 AND MODEL2)

Comment: class ProfileSize(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sizes')

Comment: can you try to simply assign this part `Model1.objects.filter(user=request.user).last().field1.name` to a variable and show the output, we have to understand where exactly the error is coming from

Comment: if i try that the value was printed normaly in my terminal: the code:  if request.method == 'GET': form = FormAssembly(instance=request.user, ) var = Geometry.objects.filter(user=request.user).last().sizes.name print (var)